# Disable javascript type coercion warning in Resharper

Tags: javascript, resharper, resharper-9.0

Since installing ReSharper 9, I noticed that it now highlights parts of javascript code where a type coercion occurs:

```
'==' tries to coerce values before comparing them which can lead to some unexpected results
```

Is it possible to disable these warnings? I've had a quick look in Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> Javascript, but can't find the option I'm looking for anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found the answer myself:

Resharper -> Options -> **Code Inspection** -> Inspection Severity

In JS tab

> Using of coerced equality operator

has to be set to

> '**Do not show**'

Comment: maybe you should consider using === instead. Check the "Problems When Using == or != Comparison Operators" section in this link http://appendto.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-2/

Comment: Yes, I am aware of differences, however sometimes one knows that two values are in fact the same and there's no need to care about Resharper trying to improve your coding standards (especially while working on legacy systems).